# space between firstname and lastname

Tags: apex

How do I add a space between `FirstName` and `LastName`? I have tried below code, but I am not able to see any space between contact `FirstName` and `LastName`.

```
String body = 'Hi  ';
    if(u.FirstName!=null)
        body=body+u.FirstName ' ;
    if(u.LastName!=null)
        body=body+u.LastName ;
body=body+'<br/><br/>';
```

Comment: What about creating a formula field and referring that no code required

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to close the single quote(**'**) `body=body+u.FirstName ' ;` and we can use the shorthand operator like: `body += ...;` instead of `body = body + ...;`

Try this code instead:

```
String body = 'Hi';
if(u.FirstName != null){
  body += ' ' + u.FirstName;
}

if(u.LastName != null){
  body += ' ' + u.LastName;
}

body += '<br/><br/>';
```

Comment: That's much better, although there was something else missing in the OP as well (concatenation operator).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do it this way, meaning the spaces between the letters what you should take out of this is `+=` [String Concatenate +=](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154075/string-concatenate)

```
String body = 'Hi  ';
if(u.FirstName!=null)
{
    body += u.FirstName + ' ';
}
if(u.LastName!=null)
{
    body += u.LastName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format you're looking for is `<first/given name> <last/family name>`, and assuming that you are working with a `User` record, then you could avoid work by simply using the standard `Name` field, which concatenates first & last name with a single space added automatically in between.

```
String body = 'Hi ' + u.Name + '<br /><br />';
// result would be
// 'Hi Marc Benioff<br /><br />';
```